# Extra wear of multicore processor when only a single core is used. Is there such a thing?

Tags: cpu, cooling, physical-wear

There are specific processes that seem to load only one of the processor cores, out of the eight cores my processor has.

I have some such processes that run only 10-20 seconds, but others run in this fashion for up to 1.5-3 minutes.

During this my cooling fan can speed up to really intense rates.

I was thinking, if there is so much heat to deal with, while it is being concentrated on only one core, then is it possible — considering the entire area of the processor — that some part is getting hot while the opposite end/corner isn't so much?

When considering heat expansion in materials, shouldn't it mean that the processor's materials are under extra stress and may be driven to develop cracks from the uneven expansion?

Is this how it happens really?

Can there be a difference in this regard between processors used in laptops (smaller, I guess) and processors used on traditional format motherboards?

---

**Clarification 1:**

I am not interested in the effects of heat when:

- its origin is distributed evenly across the processor body
- when it is encountered in a constant / long-term fashion.

This question is specifically about **heat-expansion** involving the processor, while

- happening in an **uneven distribution**,
- happening in cyclical bursts.

---

**Clarification 2:**

The post that is suggested to contain answers for this question (in the "duplicate" marking), in fact does not take uneven distribution into consideration, and addresses a lot of peripherals, but not does not seem to go into depth of heat distribution in, and material engineering of processors.

Comment: There is indeed a significant difference between a desktop and a mobile processors.  Mobile processors are designed to run on a (relatively) lower amount of power compared to a comparable desktop processor from the same generation (i.e. 10th Gen Core processor)

Comment: CPUs are not like brake pads. They don't wear out through use in any directly-measurable way.

Comment: Integrated circuits (CPU) do no crack because of normal heat. They are designed to withstand the device's top end thermal limit without physical damage.

Comment: @John Yeah, but when it's significantly unevenly distributed?

Comment: A small device like an IC will not be damaged by any uneveness in temperature distribution within the device. The heatsink will cool down all parts of the device.

Comment: @Levente - CPUs were designed to operate in the way you describe.

Comment: Heatsinks are designed to be good thermal conductors. Any heat put out by one individual core will be quickly absorbed by the heatsink and distributed, effectively warming up all cores. If it were not the even the most basic single core task would kill the CPU immediately by all sorts of methods. Heat is dissipated and shared across the substrate and heatsink.

Comment: @Levente - I unfortunately do not agree that this question is within scope, specifically, due to this specific part of the question: *but not does not seem to go into depth of heat distribution in, and material engineering of processors.* There more specialized SE communities for questions about product engineering.  So I won’t attempt to answer it until it is

Comment: I have read https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask and https://superuser.com/help/on-topic The on-topic page says "If you have a question about … computer hardware" — and then there is no such condition in neither of the linked two pages that would rule this out.

Comment: @Levente - I am not sure we are the community to talk about the material engineering process of computer processors.  There might be a few material engineers that lurk in the shadows, but designing a IC that contains billions of resistors, is a little bit more complicate. While I have designed my own simply IC, even had it manufactured, choosing which materials is was composed of was beyond even my skillset (it was a submit your design and we produce it type deal).

Comment: I believe the correct version of the key term here is "**thermal-expansion**"; I should have written that.